# Error while installing Pillow on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I just was trying to install yowsup on my new Raspberry Pi. Everything went fine, until it was about to install Pillow. I got the following error message:

```
Processing dependencies for yowsup2==2.4
Searching for pillow
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
Best match: Pillow 3.0.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pillow/Pillow-3.0.0.zip#md5=dd81f6cc3f3a5e5fe72f0f1d936339c3
Processing Pillow-3.0.0.zip
Running Pillow-3.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-AlZEzs/Pillow-3.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-rX2XN3
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_innerTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 353, in _handle_tasks  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 329, in _handle_workers
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception
TypeError<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
: TypeError("'NoneType' object does not support item deletion",) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 42, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 73, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 101, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 368, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 588, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 640, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 692, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 821, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 833, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 608, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 638, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 828, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1105, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1094, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 30, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 72, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 767, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 179, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 166, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 20, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions

ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
```

I googeled it for at least an hour, but couldn't find a correct answer. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: You still don't have the complete traceback, though...

Comment: You are right - there was one line missing. Now it's the whole traceback. Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to install PIL without the proper packages installed beforehand. Try installing libjpeg.

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [External Libraries](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html#external-libraries) section of the Pillow docs, you'll see that there are a number of libraries that should be present, including `libjpeg` and `zlib`. If you don't want JPEG support, you should download the "source" archive from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.0.0), unzip it, then in the resulting directory run `python setup.py install --disable-jpeg`.

However, I wouldn't recommend this, as you won't be able to process JPEGs with Pillow. Instead, use the package manager on your Pi to install all of the libraries for which you'd like support, then re-run `pip install pillow`.